# Visual studio localhost loading without open page in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, blazor

This happens the last 2 days.
The Chrome browser is loading with an empty page.
Firefox opens the page correctly. Any idea about that?

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

The page loads in chrome if I disable script debugging but then I cannot debug Javascript.
Any idea how can I fix this and manage to work with chrome and javascript debugging in Visual Studio?

Comment: I've run into this before and cleaning the solution can help, delete `bin` and `obj` folders.

Comment: I did it but didn't help unfortunately. Seems that if I change the order of script tags in layout.cshtml makes page partially load but continues to not work

Comment: How can I see the error? I see a blank page without errors in console

Comment: nothing in the developer `Console` tab?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Could it be a javascript code error? Or a javascript combatiblity issue between libraries?

Answer (score 0):

If I use Internet explorer as browser I get

```
   crbug/1173575 (index):1957
```